# Google fonts bug on apple devices

Tags: fonts

for some reason I've got an incorrect rendering of the Google font named "Inter". I've tried to include different file types like .svg .woff2 or .ttf. Nothing helped.

Here you can see a screenshot of the issue:

[image: google font bug example screenshot]

Has anyone run into the same issue and knows how to fix it?

Best regards!